# "Generic parameter 'ResultType' could not be inferred" while use NSFetchRequest() with swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

While I convert my project to swift 3.0 , I found that error

> parameter 'ResultType' could not be inferred

My code like this :

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book")
```

I use this code in my project before,and now it appears error.How shell I modify it right.

Comment: Try with this let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book")

Answer (score 12):

It should be like

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Book> = Book.fetchRequest()
```

And your **Book+CoreDataProperties.swift** file for **Swift 3** will be like this

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Book {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Book> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Book>(entityName: "Book");
    }

    @NSManaged public var bookName: String?

}
```